# Get the URL of RSS Feed Enclosure Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss, jfeed

Developers!

I'm having some trouble understanding the rss feed enclosure tag..
Here you got the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#btnHentRss').click(function(){
        fyllNyheter();
    });

});

    function fyllNyheter(){

        var url = $('#feedListe').val();

            $.getFeed({
                url: "getRSS.php?url=" + url,
                success: function(feed){
                     parseXML(feed);
            },
            error: function(){
                $('#sectId').html("<p>Something went wrong</p>");
            },
            complete: function(){

            }
        });

}
 function parseXML(feed){

       $.each(feed.items, function(i, item){
                var tittel = item.title;
                var beskrivelse = item.description;
                var url= $(item).find("enclosure['url']");

                $('#sectId').append("<img src='" + media + "' />");
            }); 
}
```

Example of the xml:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">
<channel>
<title>NRK - Musikknyheter</title>
<link>http://nrk.no/liste.rss</link>
<description>Musikknyheter</description>
<pubDate>Sat, 13 Oct 2012 16:20:47 +0200</pubDate>
<sy:updateFrequency>12</sy:updateFrequency>
<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
<item>
<title>Ny slagkraftig festspillprodusent</title>
<link>http://www.nrk.no/nyheter/distrikt/troms_og_finnmark/1.8354920</link>
<description>Festspillene i Nord-Norge har ansatt Nasra Ali Omar som ny produsent for barn og unge.</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 11 Oct 2012 14:41:39 +0200</pubDate>
<enclosure url="http://www.nrk.no/contentfile/imagecrop/1.6102705?cropid=f169w225" type="image/jpeg"/>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

`var tittel` returns the correct title of each item(So I know I got contact with the feed).

`var url` only returns [Object object].

I'm using jFeed. See the jFeed php and js here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbuNW/

What am I supposed to do? My google searches has turned purple, I don't want to use another plugin, and I want to do it in javascript/jquery.

Thanks for even reading my problem :) Happy problem solving!

Comment: `$(item).find("enclosure['url']").text()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED Answer after xml was posted:

`url` is an attribute of the `enclosure` tag

Use:

```
var url =  $(item).find("enclosure").attr('url')
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/AV4ms/

Comment: I dont think it's the text I'm looking for, I need the attribute URL's content. Your solution gave me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of undefined "

Comment: post some of the xml, probably have to escape the "[]" and if is an attribute would be different selector and use `attr()` method

Comment: revised solution using `attr()` method

Comment: I see your fiddle works fine. Somehow I get undefined when defining `var media = $(item).find("enclosure").attr("url");`

Comment: problem is `$.each(feed.items`. Cose is typically for an object not xml. What are you passing to `parseXML` ?  SHow more code in ajax success

Comment: looked at this again..post a link to plugin docs. The ajax I asked about is handled by plugin

Comment: Download php here: http://www.2shared.com/file/mlXMF1ux/getRSS.html?    and the js here: http://www.2shared.com/document/UsjdH773/jqueryjfeed.html

Comment: these are downloads...post link to online docs and demos. Idea of downloads for people trying to help you makes no sense.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are absolutely right. Take look at this fiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/zbuNW/ .. Thanks for being patient

Comment: post link to live page that fails so can inspect feed issue in browser console

Comment: OK..problem is using the plugin itself since it doesn't pass the `enclosure` tag for you to access. Either need to rewrite the plugin ( which is old) or find a newer one that is more flexible. Modifying the plugin wouldn't be very difficult, but is hard at this end to modify without being able to run simple tests in browser using live xml

Comment: look at plugin code and how it gets "link" tag in the plugin code... would need similar for `enclosure` tag, and then `media=item.enclosure`

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I've got it to work by adding ` item.enclosure = jQuery(this).find('enclosure').eq(0).attr('url');` to the last .each() in the plugin js :) We should probably clean up this comments?

Answer (score 0):

If your xml feed tag is of the type like this

```
<link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" length="2893" href="http://imgs.server.com/2010/06/imagethumb.jpg"/>
```

then you should use the Selector lk

```
var img = $(this).find('link[rel|="enclosure"]').attr('href');
```

in your code

[Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/)